# Get value in case-insensitive HashSet<string>

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I have case-insensitive `HashSet<string>`:

```
private HashSet<string> a = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

I'm curious if I can now extract the string in the actual case. Pseudo code of what I need:

```
return a.Contains(word) ? a[word] : null;
```

(just a pseudo code, it won't work)

For example, I have string "**TestXxX**" in the HashSet. I need for the code which gets "testxxx" (or "tEsTXXx") as input and returns "**TestXxX**".

My current workaround is to use `Dictionary<string,string>` instead and put the same value for both key and value. This is obviously not elegant and consumes 2x memory as it actually needs.

Comment: Sets don't normally contain indexes. You'll either have to switch to `List<T>` or create a strongly typed class that derives from `KeyedCollection<T, T>`

Comment: If you no longer need the set, you might `IntersectWith(new [] { word })` and iterate over the result, I think. But it's obviously not a general solution: cloning the set just to get one item is needless work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override [`KeyedCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class Keyed : KeyedCollection<string, string>
{
    public Keyed(IEqualityComparer<string> comparer) : base(comparer)
    {

    }

    protected override string GetKeyForItem(string item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var keyed = new Keyed(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
keyed.Add("TestXxX");

Console.WriteLine(keyed["tEsTXXx"]);
```

Comment: How does this work?  Wouldn't `GetKeyForItem(string item)` have to return `string.ToLower(item)`?  What am I missing?

Comment: @Adrian, the code above works. The answer is quite old, so now I wouldn't bother with KeyedCollection, I would simply use `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet<T>` doesn't expose any functionality to achieve what you're looking for. If you don't need to use a `HashSet`, then Kirill Polishchuk's answer makes sense to me.

Otherwise, if you do need a `HashSet`, a somewhat nasty hack is to use a custom equality comparer. Create your own equality comparer that simply forwards all requests to `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, but caches the last-passed objects.

If you have that, then after `a.Contains(word)` returns `true`, the last-passed objects *should* be 1) `word` and 2) the word as it appears in `a`.

Strictly speaking, this is not guaranteed to work, since `HashSet` is allowed to call the comparer with different values than what you expect. It's certain to work in current versions of .NET Framework though and unlikely to break in the future: the comparer equality function obviously needs to be called with those arguments in order for `Contains` to return the correct value, and there is no reason why it would be called with any other arguments except to intentionally break code like this.